# Error while converting string to Datetime

Tags: c#

I have string value `7/29/2000`. When I convert it to date time it's giving an error. Error Message: `Cannot convert string to Datetime`

```
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
string oldValue = decrypt.Decrypt(dtOldI9Value.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString().Trim());
DateTime dtOldValue = DateTime.Parse(oldValue, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

From the 3 rd line i am getting the value as "7/29/2000". Please help me.

Comment: what does decrypt do ? Have you stepped into line 3 to see what's actually inside oldValue ?

Comment: Put a break point on third line and see what is inside oldValue

Comment: 3rd line oldValue="07/29/2000"

Comment: Try to log `dtOldI9Value.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString().Trim()` to see if the date is well formatted

Comment: Sorry for the wrong value.Actual value is "7/29/2000"

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting this value as DateTime?

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dtOldValue = DateTime.Parse("07/29/2000", provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
Console.WriteLine(dtOldValue);
```

So there must be something with your `decrypt.Decrypt()`. Are you sure it doesn't adds characters to `oldValue`? Check `oldValue.Length`, it should be 10.

Comment: +1 for the lenght check. With a method called decrypt, is there a possibility for none-displayable characters in the string?

Comment: Actual value is "7/29/2000" with 9 length